# Validate multiple versions of an object against XSD

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, attributes, version

I would like to validate against XSD multiple versions of an object. I was thinking of using an attribute to declare the version.

Suppose I have a 1st version:

```
<person version="1.0">
  <firstname></firstname>
  <lastname></lastname>
</person>
```

And a 2nd version:

```
<person version="2.0">
  <firstname></firstname>
  <lastname></lastname>
  <birthdate></birthdate>
</person>
```

Can I do something like this? What's the best solution to model these two objects in XSD?

Answer (score 2):

In XSD 1.1 you can use conditional type attribution (or "type alternatives") where you declare the type of the element based on the value of one of its attributes, using an XPath predicate.

There's no equivalent in XSD 1.0.